# Should accessors be Inlined?

Tags: c++, inline

This is the declaration in the header file:

```
class PrimeSieve  
{
    populate(int lim);
    vector<int> sieve;
    long long limit;

    public:
        unsigned int limit();
};
```

Should I define the accessor method in the .cpp file or in the .h, inline?

I'm new to C++, but I'd like to follow best practices. I've seen this around in some of the books—is this considered standard?

```
unsigned int limit() { return limit; };
```

Comment: I think this could probably be expanded to "should reasonably short functions be inlined?".

Comment: You're missing a `const`, btw.

Comment: Note that you can define the function as inline, still in the header file, but outside the class body.  This sometimes results in more readable interface.  In your case, you'd keep the the class declaration the same as the "out of line" way, but you'd move the function definition to the header file, with `inline` before it.

Comment: fyi, the limit private member and the limit() pubic accessor method are declared as different types (long long and unsigned int, respectively)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Definitely write the accessor inline in the header file.  It makes better optimizations possible, and doesn't reduce encapsulation (since changes to the format of private data require recompiling all units that include the header anyway).

In the case of a complicated algorithm, you might want to hide the definition in an implementation file.  Or when the implementation requires some types/header files not otherwise required by the class definition.  Neither of those cases applies to simple accessors.

For one-liners, put it inside the class definition.  Slightly longer member functions should still be in the header file, but might be declared explicitly `inline`, following the class definition.

Comment: If there are a bunch of inline methods, I'll also stick them in an ".inl" file and stick #include "MyClass.inl" at the bottom of MyClass.h so that my header file remains a little clean (clients of MyClass should not need to know implementation details, even inline methods).

Answer (score 7):

Most newer compilers are smart enough to inline what is necessary and leave everything else alone.  So let the compiler do what its good at and don't try to second guess it.

Put all your code in the .cpp and the code declarations in the .h.

Comment: By "definitions" you mean "declarations". And . . . your answer doesn't really make sense to me. If you're putting the method's implementation in a .cpp file, then how is the compiler supposed to inline occurrences of it in other .cpp files?

Comment: Re: definitions vs. declarations: Not at all! It's a really important difference in C++. What you're calling "code" is actually "definitions", and what you're calling "code definitions" is actually "declarations". Re: link-time optimization: good to know, thanks! (P.S. I'm sorry for my earlier comment, which I've now deleted; in retrospect I think I worded it rudely. I see that it had gotten four "this is a great comment" votes, so maybe it was fine, but . . . yeah. I'm sorry.)

Comment: @GregorBrandt: Many compilers in production use are not bleeding edge, while C++-LTO is bleeding edge compiler technology. Also: Do you know that LTO support must usually be requested explicitly, or do you expect the compiler to do it all automatically for you?

Answer (score 0):

A good rule of thumb is to put all your code in the .cpp file, so this would argue against an inline function in the .h file.

Answer (score 0):

For simple data types in classes fully visible to clients of the class, there is no real difference as you need to recompile the client whenever the class definition changes.

The main reason to make an accessor rather than use the member directly is to allow the implementation to remove the data member later on and still keep the interface compatible; if the interface containing the accessor is unchanged, the result is typically binary compatible, otherwise, it's source compatible. Having the accessor inline means defining it as part of the interface that you are changing, so you can ever only be source compatible.

The other reason to have an accessor is a DLL boundary: If your accessor needs to call into another function, and you allow it to be inlined, then this function's symbol needs to be exported to the client as well.

Depending on the complexity of the project, it can be beneficial to define an interface for your code as an abstract class, which allows you to change the implementation to your heart's content without the client ever seeing the change; in this case, accessors are defined as abstract in the interface class and clients cannot inline them, ever.

Answer (score 0):

The argument for declaring the accessor `inline` is that this eliminates the call over-head, and can enable some further optimisations.

My experienced of *measured performance* is that the gain from doing this is usually rather modest. I consequently no longer do it by default.

Answer (score -1):

More than being kind of global programming standards, these vary from organizations to organizaions. Of course, `getLimit()` would still be better than mere `limit()`.

Comment: `getLimit` isn't canonical C++ style.

Comment: Wait, aren't you contradicting yourself? You say that, as a coding standard, it varies from organization to organization, and then claim than `getLimit` is better than `limit`, despite the fact that this is too a coding standard?

Comment: But it is far more clear than mere `limit()`, something is better than canonical, then better must prevail.

Comment: @check123: The Standard library has many classes which has members like `size()` as opposed to `getSize()/get_size()/GetSize()`.

Comment: I agree, but its just more intuitive.

Comment: It's a matter of personal taste. I don't find it more intuitive.

Comment: @check123: Only if you come from languages like Java and C#. I find `size()` better, as it could be overloaded as `size(int s)` to set size. So when there is no argument, it is get size, but when there is argument, it is set size.

Comment: 'It'a matter of personal taste' that sums it up pretty well. :) This debate is going nowhere.

Comment: @Nawaz Even then, in .NET it's better style to use properties.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: Oh yes. I forgot that. I think, now `size()` appears more consistent even with .Net style coding.

Comment: @check123: Of course it's matter of taste, but let me give you an example why some people prefer `limit` over `getLimit`:  `if (foo.limit() > 4)` reads more like `if foo's limit is bigger than 4`, whereas `if (foo.getLimit())` sounds a bit like `if foo's get limit is bigger than, wait what?` ;)

Comment: if the method is simply named `limit` it can be interpreted as a verb, as most methods are.  Using `getlimit` makes it clear that limit is a noun.